# MVVMCross minimum Android / iOS versions supported

Tags: mvvmcross

What are the minimum versions of Android / iOS supported by MVVMCross? Are there any plans to change these in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until very recently (last few weeks) the majoirty of MvvmCross/Android was built using Android 1.6 as the SDK version.

The exception to this is `FullFragging` which relies on Android 3 (Honeycomb) fragment functionality - `Fragging` is there along with the Android support library for earlier versions.

In recent weeks we've changed this so that `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Android` must be compiled with at least the Honeycomb 3.1 SDK - but it is **still built to support earlier versions** using code like:

```
            if (Context.ApplicationInfo.TargetSdkVersion
                >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Honeycomb)
            {
                firstChild.Activated = value;
            }
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxBaseListItemView.cs#L168

---

> Are there any plans to change these in the future?

There are no plans to change these currently.

There are plans to continually review the project - especially in light of what users need (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/The-MvvmCross-Manifesto)

MvvmCross has been slow to move in the past - e.g. we clung to WP7 as long as we could - and even then kept support for 8 months after announcing it's tombstoning. Our users (including my customers) have typically asked for backwards compatability - so we've typically tried to oblige.

With current market trends, I suspect the major factor for any future change might be Amazon changing the Kindle platform - currently it is one of the major reasons for continuing our 2.x support. However, beyond this, there are other reasons - e.g. I have customers who've deployed WinCE-replacement apps on to Android 2.x devices and they'd prefer I continue supporting them.

---

Disclaimer: Much of MvvmCross is about plugins - e.g. rx binding from https://github.com/exram - these plugins are produced independently and can include code which only targets more modern Android versions.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, great answer. Thanks for the exram tip as well. I'll have a look.